Moving a Sharepoint file using MSGraph API in Python
I am trying to utilize the MSGraph API in Python in order to move SharePoint files around based on some input. I currently have the download part of the API settled, but moving the file does not work for some reason. Here's my code:
async def _move_sharepoint_file(self, url, site_name, src_drive_path, file_name, dst_site_name, dst_drive_path, new_file_name=None):
    # Get source site and its drive items
        sites = await self.user_client.sites.with_url(url).get()
        for site in sites.value:
            if site.name == site_name:
                src_site_id = site.id
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Source site with name '{site_name}' not found")

        # Get destination site
        if site_name == dst_site_name:
            dst_site_id = src_site_id
            
            
        else:
            for site in sites.value:
                if site.name == dst_site_name:
                    
                    dst_site_id = site.id
                    
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Destination site with name '{dst_site_name}' not found")

        # Find the source item
        src_item_id = await self.get_item_id(src_site_id, src_drive_path, file_name)
        
        if src_item_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Item with name '{file_name}' in path '{src_drive_path}' not found")
        query_params = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            filter = True
        )

        request_configuration = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters = query_params,
        )
        
        path_list = dst_drive_path.replace("\\", "/").split('/')
        drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(dst_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        drive_items = drive_items.value
        
        partial_dir = ""
        print(f"path_list: {path_list}")
        for dir in path_list:
            if len(path_list) == 1 and path_list[0] == "":
                correct_drive_items = drive_items
                break
            else:
                partial_dir += f"/{dir}"
            print(f"partial_dir: {partial_dir}") if self.verbose else None
            [print(f"drive: {drive.name}") for drive in drive_items] if self.verbose else None
            print() if self.verbose else None
            for drive_item in drive_items:
                if drive_item.name == dir and hasattr(drive_item, 'folder'):  # Check if the item has 'folder' attribute
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Folder with name '{partial_dir}' not found")

            drive_id = drive_item.id  # Assume this item is the folder
            print(f"Selected Folder Name: {drive_item.name}, ID: {drive_id}")

        dst_folder_id = drive_id #await self.get_item_id(dst_site_id, dst_drive_path, None)
          # Assuming you pass None for file_name to get the folder ID
        if dst_folder_id is None:
            raise ValueError(f"Destination path '{dst_drive_path}' not found")

        # Prepare the request body
        request_body = DriveItem(
            parent_reference=ItemReference(id=dst_folder_id),
            name=new_file_name if new_file_name else file_name
        )

        # Move the item by updating its parent reference
        result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(src_item_id).patch(request_body)
        if result.is_success:
            print("File moved successfully.")
            return result.content
        else:
            print(f"Failed to move file. Status code: {result.status_code}")
            return None

When trying to run this code, I eventually receive the error (blurred out the request id's):
msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error.ODataError:
        APIError
        Code: 403
        message: None
        error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='accessDenied', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={}, client_request_id='XXXXX', date=DateTime(2024, 5, 14, 7, 6, 52, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), odata_type=None, request_id='XXXX'), message='Access denied', target=None)

Please note that I do have the right permissions to the SharePoint sites I am trying to access. Also we have the correct rights (file.readwrite.all).
My colleague is the one who wrote the download part, but I was given the task to extend this and add a move function. Here is the download function that actually does work:
async def _download_sharepoint_file(self, url, site_name, drive_path, file_names, dst_path=None):
        # Deze functie aanroepen werkt niet met asyncio, dus die heb ik gekopieerd en geplakt
        # drive = await self.get_sharepoint_site_drive_contents(url, site_name, drive_path)
        sites = await self.user_client.sites.with_url(url).get()
        
        print(f"Sites:") if self.verbose else None    
        [print(f"site: {site.name}") for site in sites.value] if self.verbose else None
        print() if self.verbose else None

        for site in sites.value:
            if site.name == site_name:
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Site with name '{site_name}' not found")
        
        site_id = site.id

        query_params = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
            filter = True
        )

        request_configuration = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
            query_parameters = query_params,
        )
        
        path_list = drive_path.replace("\\", "/").split('/')
        print(path_list)
        drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
        drive_items = drive_items.value
        
        partial_dir = ""
        print(f"path_list: {path_list}")
        for dir in path_list:
            if len(path_list) == 1 and path_list[0] == "":
                
                correct_drive_items = drive_items
                
                break
            else:
                partial_dir += f"/{dir}"
            print(f"partial_dir: {partial_dir}") if self.verbose else None
            [print(f"drive: {drive.name}") for drive in drive_items] if self.verbose else None
            print() if self.verbose else None
            for drive_item in drive_items:
                if drive_item.name == dir:
                    break
            else:
                raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{partial_dir}' not found")
            
            drive_id = drive_item.id
            drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(drive_id).children.get()
            drive_items = drive_items.value
            
            correct_drive_items = []
            for drive_item in drive_items:
                print(f"drive_item.name: {drive_item.name}") if self.verbose else None
                parent_path = drive_item.parent_reference.path
                print(f"drive_item.parent_reference.path: {drive_item.parent_reference.path}") if self.verbose else None
                if parent_path.endswith(partial_dir):
                    correct_drive_items.append(drive_item)
                    print(f"YES") if self.verbose else None
                
        drives = correct_drive_items
        #### Einde van get_sharepoint_site_drive_contents

        [print(f"drive_item.name: {drive_item.name}") for drive_item in drives] if self.verbose else None
        if isinstance(file_names, str):
            file_names = [file_names]
        drives = [drive for drive in drives if drive.name in file_names]
        if len(drives) == 0:    
            raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{file_names}' not found")
        
        for drive, file_name in zip(drives, file_names):
            drive_id = drive.id
            parent_drive_id = drive.parent_reference.drive_id
            print(f"drive_id; {drive_id}") if self.verbose else None
            print(f"parent_drive_id: {parent_drive_id}") if self.verbose else None
            try:
                result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(parent_drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(drive_id).content.get()
                
            except:
                result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(parent_drive_id).items.by_drive_item_id(drive_id).get()
                
            if not dst_path:
                return result
            
            _, ext_sp = os.path.splitext(drive.name)
            _, ext = os.path.splitext(file_name)
            assert ext_sp == ext, f"Extensions do not match: {ext_sp} != {ext}"

            if isinstance(result, DriveItem):
                return result

            with open(f"{dst_path}/{file_name}", "wb") as f:
                f.write(result)
            print(f"File saved as: {dst_path}/{file_name}") if self.verbose else None

        return result

I have been struggling with this since yesterday, but everything I try ends up with the same or some other error. I would appreciate it if anyone knows how to fix this error.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

@СергейКох So I am trying to bugfix the move_sharepoint_file function, but when trying to run the code, I receive the error:msgraph.generated.models.o_data_errors.o_data_error.ODataError:
APIError
Code: 403
message: None
error: MainError(additional_data={}, code='accessDenied', details=None, inner_error=InnerError(additional_data={}, client_request_id='XXXXX', date=DateTime(2024, 5, 14, 7, 6, 52, tzinfo=Timezone('UTC')), odata_type=None, request_id='XXXX'), message='Access denied', target=None)

async def _move_sharepoint_file(self, url, site_name, src_drive_path, file_name, dst_site_name, dst_drive_path, new_file_name=None):
    # Check permissions and verify authentication - ensure proper scopes are included in token
    
    # Get source site and its drive items
    sites = await self.user_client.sites.with_url(url).get()
    src_site_id = None
    dst_site_id = None
    
    for site in sites.value:
        print(site.name)
        if site.name == site_name:
            src_site_id = site.id
        if site.name == dst_site_name:
            dst_site_id = site.id
    print(f"src_site_id: {src_site_id}")
    # if src_site_id is None:
    #     raise ValueError(f"Source site with name '{site_name}' not found")
    # if dst_site_id is None:
    #     raise ValueError(f"Destination site with name '{dst_site_name}' not found")
    query_params = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetQueryParameters(
        filter = True
    )
    request_configuration = ItemsRequestBuilder.ItemsRequestBuilderGetRequestConfiguration(
        query_parameters = query_params,
    )
    
    path_list = src_drive_path.replace("\\", "/").split('/')
    print(path_list)
    drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
    drive_items = drive_items.value
    
    partial_dir = ""
    print(f"path_list: {path_list}")
    for dir in path_list:
        if len(path_list) == 1 and path_list[0] == "":
            
            correct_drive_items = drive_items
            
            break
        else:
            partial_dir += f"/{dir}"
        print(f"partial_dir: {partial_dir}") if self.verbose else None
        [print(f"drive: {drive.name}") for drive in drive_items] if self.verbose else None
        print() if self.verbose else None
        for drive_item in drive_items:
            if drive_item.name == dir:
                break
        else:
            raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{partial_dir}' not found")
        
        drive_id = drive_item.id
        drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(drive_id).children.get()
        drive_items = drive_items.value
        
        correct_drive_items = []
        for drive_item in drive_items:
            print(f"drive_item.name: {drive_item.name}") if self.verbose else None
            parent_path = drive_item.parent_reference.path
            print(f"drive_item.parent_reference.path: {drive_item.parent_reference.path}") if self.verbose else None
            if parent_path.endswith(partial_dir):
                correct_drive_items.append(drive_item)
                print(f"YES") if self.verbose else None
    drives = correct_drive_items
    drives = [drive for drive in drives if drive.name in file_name]
    if len(drives) == 0:    
        raise ValueError(f"Drive with name '{file_name}' not found")
    
    for drive, file_name in zip(drives, file_name):
        src_item_id = drive.id
        parent_drive_id = drive.parent_reference.drive_id
        print(f"LOOOOOL {src_item_id}")
    # Find the source item
    #src_item_id = await self.get_item_id(src_site_id, src_drive_path, file_name)
    # Get destination folder ID
    dst_drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(dst_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
    dst_folder_id = None
    for drive_item in dst_drive_items.value:
        print(drive_item.name)
        if drive_item.name == dst_drive_path.split('/')[-1]:
            dst_folder_id = drive_item.id
            break
    
    
    if src_item_id is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Item with name '{file_name}' in path '{src_drive_path}' not found")
    if dst_folder_id is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Destination folder '{dst_drive_path}' not found")
    # Get source drive ID
    src_drive_items = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.get(request_configuration=request_configuration)
    src_drive_id = None
    for drive_item in src_drive_items.value:
        if drive_item.name == src_drive_path:
            src_drive_id = drive_item.id
            break
    
    if src_drive_id is None:
        raise ValueError(f"Source drive '{src_drive_path}' not found")
    # Prepare the request body
    request_body = {
        "parentReference": {"driveId": dst_site_id, "id": dst_folder_id},
        "name": new_file_name if new_file_name else file_name
    }
    #request_body_json = json.dumps(request_body)
    # Move the item by updating its parent reference
    result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(src_item_id).patch(body=request_body)
    
    if result.is_success:
        print("File moved successfully.")
        return result.content
    else:
        print(f"Failed to move file. Status code: {result.status_code}")
        return None

I fixed the permission errors, but now I get the following error:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'serialize'
for the code
request_body = {
        "parentReference": {"driveId": dst_site_id, "id": dst_folder_id},
        "name": new_file_name if new_file_name else file_name
}
#request_body_json = json.dumps(request_body)
# Move the item by updating its parent reference
result = await self.user_client.drives.by_drive_id(src_site_id).items.by_drive_item_id(src_item_id).patch(body=request_body)

